# Flutter Archive app to testflight gives error ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, testflight

I'm developing a Flutter application and trying to upload a new build to testFlight

> flutter doctor -v
>
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac
> OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale
> en-US)
> • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/shadysherif/Documents/Dev/flutter
> • Framework revision 68587a0916 (10 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
> • Engine revision b863200c37
> • Dart version 2.5.0
>
> [✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
> ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
> Install Android Studio from:
> https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
> On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
> components.
> (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
> instructions).
> If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
> ANDROID_HOME to that location.
> You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
> • CocoaPods version 1.9.3
>
> [!] Android Studio (not installed)
> • Android Studio not found; download from
> https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
> (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
> instructions).
>
> [!] Connected device
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

### Problem #1

After archiving the application and uploading it to testFlight, I got a success message but I can't find any build on the testFlight. I waited more than 10 minutes and testFlight shows `no builds`. I tried many times and I also tried to export instead of the upload because a colleague told me It could be XCode issue while uploading and I used the tool and I had no luck.

[image]

**Finally, I found that the errors were sent as an email to my developer account email !!!**

### Problem #2

I'm happy that I found the error and here all the details:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "app name" version. Please correct the
> following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _ptrace. If method
> names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
> altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
> flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
> the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
> with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information,
> visit the Technical Support Information at
> http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I didn't find much help online

Comment: You should run `flutter analyze` and fix any issues that mention private API usage. Also a `dart fix` could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wired issue, and I don't know why the Xcode compiles and archives the development symbols!

the solution is simple, Run the commands at the root of your flutter project

```
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
flutter build ios --release
```

Then product -> archive, the build will be uploaded directly to the TestFlight, but it may take a while to process.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the clang tooling flutter uses referenced an internal api.
See flutter engine fix here https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/44442
Possible clang commit https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/b653a2823fe4b4c9c6d85cfe119f31d8e70c2fa0

Answer (score 0):

okay,
i got this issue when i upgraded and change my flutter channel from stable to master.

what i did was simply return it (downgrade) it back and change the flutter channel to stable.

i hope this help someone out there with this similar issues